# CGPath performance problems when redrawing

Tags: ios, xcode, cgpath

i have some strange problems with the performance of the app i am working on at the moment. One View uses a self build infographic, that is similar to a polarchart. it is redrawn every 8 seconds. 
the first five times it is redrawn everything is fine, but afterwards the scroll view which is the superview of the view that shows the infographic starts to heavily to stutter. here are the essential parts of the code, which produces the graphic.

[_chartLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    _chartLayer = [CALayer layer];

```
  CAShapeLayer *segment = [mySegmentProducer produceSegmentWith:startAngle and: endAngle and: radius and: sliceAngle];
    [_chartLayer addSublayer:segment];
    [self.layer addSublayer:_chartLayer];
```

and here is the function "produceSegmentWith:" placed in the other class:

```
- (CAShapeLayer*) produceSegmentWith:(float)startAngle and:(float)endAngle and:(float) radius and: (float) sliceAngle  {

CAShapeLayer *segment = [CAShapeLayer layer];

CGPathRef pathTwo = [self addSegmentPath: radius fromStartAngle:startAngle toEndAngle:endAngle];

// hue = 224 / 360 initial value

segment.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:self.hue/360 saturation:0.5 brightness:0.63 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
segment.lineWidth = 0.0;
segment.path = pathTwo;
self.hue-= 15;
return segment;
```

}

I'm shure something is wrong with what I'm doing here. In other posts I saw that a function "CGPathRelease" is always used. but I am not shure how to use it correctly. When I put it right in the line above "return segment" i allways get a "BAD_THREAD_ACCESS" exception. Anyone can bring me in the right direction?

Comment: from a quick glance ... you are adding new shape layers every time... try to delete the last added before adding a new one.

Comment: The first thing you should do is run Instruments to see what's happening.

Comment: what i frogot to mention is that above tha CALayer instanciation have these functions  [_chartLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    and _chartLayer = [CALayer layer];  is _chartLayer deleted when removing it from the superlayer?